# Linux C, opening a file that exists, EEXIST error bug

Tags: c, linux, io, errno

Using this code, I am not sure why I am getting the error (EEXIST 17 File exists) after my call to open(). The file does exist.

```
int flags = O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_APPEND | S_IRWXU;
int fd = open("./atomic.txt", flags);

if(fd==-1)
{
    printf("error code: %d \n", errno);
    perror("open.. ");
    exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`S_IRWXU` is meant to be part of the *mode*, not the *flags*:

```
int flags = O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_APPEND;
int mode = S_IRWXU;
int fd = open("./atomic.txt", flags, mode);
```

Most likely what is happening is that `S_IRWXU` is setting the `O_EXCL` bit of `flags` hence `open()` will fail if the file already exists. That is *indeed* the case, at least on my system:

```
/usr/include/fcntl.h:
    #define S_IRWXU (__S_IREAD|__S_IWRITE|__S_IEXEC)
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stat.h:
    #define __S_IREAD  0400
    #define __S_IWRITE 0200
    #define __S_IEXEC  0100
/usr/include/asm-generic/fcntl.h:
    #define O_EXCL 00000200
```

You can see that the `__S_IWRITE` mode and `O_EXCL` flag are both `0200`.

Comment: By using O_CREAT, you have to set the third parameter. Look at `man 2 open`

Comment: @Gam Why doesn't it fail with `EINVAL`, then?

Comment: @Joker_vD, if you're talking about an invalid flags, it's just a bit mask, `open()` has no idea how you *populated* that bit mask. If you're talking about the missing third parameter, `open()` has no idea how many things you pushed (or what registers you set) before calling it either. It just assumes you know what you're doing :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo - `open` is supposed to fail quickly and early; at least when using glibc. It speaks to some validation and an `EINVAL` return. I'm wondering why he could call open with the incorrect number of arguments. Also see [Style and Conventions](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Style_and_Conventions) on the Sourceware wiki.

Comment: @jww, you are correct there (assuming the error *can* actually be detected). If you're talking about the `9.2` section of that link (which covers user errors), that's for undefined behaviour. There is no UB here, the user has simply erroneously set the flags variable. Given the API in use, I'm not sure it's even *possible* for this (or a missing third parameter) to be detected by `open()`.

Comment: At least on the compiler side, something like this crossed my mind, if (O_CREAT is a flag, then if only two arguments exist (absence of third ',')   ..error..